# Is it ok to call StopAsync if StartAsync has failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, resources

I'm currently working on adding a web application service to a project(with WebApplication in .NET), and I'm unsure about what to do in case the service fails to start successfully. My objective is to ensure that the process keeps running even if the service fails to start. To achieve this, I plan to catch any exceptions thrown by `StartAsync()` and continue running the process.

However, I'm uncertain about whether I should call `StopAsync()` to perform a graceful shutdown, even if `StartAsync()` failed. My concern is that if StartAsync() fails, the service might not have started or initialized correctly, and calling `StopAsync()` might cause some background jobs or services to fail.

In summary, my question is whether it is safe to call `StopAsync()` to perform a graceful shutdown, even if `StartAsync()` failed.